# isScrolledIntoView for a list of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

the isScrolledIntoView function has already been discussed several times. I would have here however still a special thing to fade in and out.

Problem: The code below should let the individual items be displayed one after the other. So that these appear with the delay gradually. Here, however, they are called at the same time. Otherwise, it works as I imagine.

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
        function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
            var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();

            var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
            var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

            return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
        }

        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (isScrolledIntoView('#fadein_product1')) {
                jQuery('#fadein_product1 img.fading').each(function() {
                inImgViewproduct1 = true;
                var delay = 500;
                    jQuery(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(2000);
                    delay += 300;                           
                });
            }
            else {
                inImgViewproduct1 = false;
                jQuery('#fadein_product1 img.fading').fadeOut();
            }
```

Comment: var delay = 500;  needs to be outside your each() function

Comment: Ups, you are absolutly right, but it does not fix my probleme with the "jumping fade in" of the img.fading objects.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work much better using CSS opacity and a different scroll function. Also I added a setTimeout into the each() function.

jQuery

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
 {
    var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();
    var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
 }



jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(e) {

    if (isScrolledIntoView('#fadein_product1')) {
       inImgViewproduct1 = true;
       jQuery('#fadein_product1 .fading').each(function(i) { 
           var el=jQuery(this);
           setTimeout(function() { 
               el.removeClass('fade');
           }, i * 300); 
       });
   } else {
       jQuery('#fadein_product1 .fading').addClass('fade');
   }
});
```

CSS

```
.fading {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s;
}
.fading.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $pc_subscription_form_wrapper = $('.pc_subscription_form_wrapper');
    var $window = $(window);
    function scroll_removeclass() {
        var window_height = $(window).height() - 0;
        var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
        var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position - window_height);

        $.each($pc_subscription_form_wrapper, function() {
            var $element = $(this);
            var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
            var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
            var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position - element_height);

            if ((element_bottom_position <= window_top_position) &&
                (element_top_position >= window_bottom_position)) {
                $element.removeClass('form_is_show');
            }
        });
    }

    function scroll_addclass() {
        var window_height = $(window).height() - 0;
        var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
        var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

        $.each($pc_subscription_form_wrapper, function() {
            var $element = $(this);
            var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
            var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
            var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

            if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
                (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
                $element.addClass('form_is_show');
            }
        });
    }

    

    $window.on('scroll resize', scroll_removeclass);
    $window.on('scroll resize', scroll_addclass);
    $window.trigger('scroll');
```

```html
<div class="pc_subscription_form_wrapper"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```